# Converting folders of .java files to .class files folder

Tags: java, windows, class

How do I convert multiple folders containing .java files to .class files having the same hierarchy? I mean just convert the .java files to .class in one go

Comment: Use `javac *.java` for compiling all files inside one folder !

Comment: he is not asking inside one folder. he is asking for multiple folders @ItachiUchiha

Comment: Sorry for posting an answer @DavidPostill didnt see that comment :(.

Comment: SORRY no offense, but it is easy to mark a thread as duplicate but not as easy for everyone to find a thread similar to the question one wants to ask.I am looking for some command like set src=dir /s /b /o:n /ad to list the directory structure with sub directories then use javac %src%\*.java to convert all .java files in the sub directories to .class file then delete the .java files

Comment: Why would you want to delete the .java files? How would you like to handle a compile error where no .class is generated and your .java has been deleted?

Comment: I would delete the java files after successfully compiling the files into class file.the thread "Java: How can I compile an entire directory structure of code?" does not give how to automatically find and compile all java files in the directory and its sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
javac /yourdir/*.java /yourdir2/*.java
```

just add the directories from which you want to compile.

Comment: :For that I would have to type each and every folder and its sub-folders name which is not practical in case of multiple folders.@DavidPostill:I am not deleting the original .java files.Will make .class files of a copy of j.ava files